# Save a PDF from bitmap into internal store or send as intent

Tags: android, itext, bit-manipulation, pdf-generation

I want to generate PDF from my bitmap, but I don't want to use external storage (in all examples how to do it they using external storage, but I don't want force users to have a SD card in phone). I want to share my PDF via intent, to send it via email or store in GoogleDrive/Phone storage. I'm using [Itext library](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf).

For now, I cannot save it on internal storage (I've got an "Error opening file: src" Toast when try to save ), moreover the google drive and mail sending also failed (got message that file cannot be upload/attached)

code:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(view);
    //Now create the name of your PDF file that you will generate
    File pdfFile = new File(CreatePDFActivity.this.getFilesDir(), "myPdfFile.pdf");

    try {
        Document document=new Document();

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath())); //  Change pdf's name.
        document.open();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image img =Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());  // Change image's name and extension.

        float scaler = ((document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin()
                         - document.rightMargin() - 0) / img.getWidth()) * 100; // 0 means you have no indentation. If you have any, change it.

        img.scalePercent(scaler);
        img.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER | Image.ALIGN_TOP);


        document.add(img);
        document.close();


        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test ");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File( CreatePDFActivity.this.getFilesDir(), "myPdfFile.pdf"));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION );
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in all examples how to do it they using external storage, but I dont want force users to have a SD card in phone

[External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). External storage is not an SD card on ~99% of Android devices in use today.

> Ive got a "Error opening file: src" Toast when try to save

There is no `Toast` in the code in your question.

> the google drive and mail sending also failed (got message that file cannot be upload/attached)

Third-party apps have no access to your app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Plus, your existing code will crash on Android 7.0+ devices, once you raise your `targetSdkVersion` to 24 or higher. Use `FileProvider` to make files saved on internal storage available to third-party apps.

Comment: I always think, that the external storage is the SD card, thanks for hints. It work correctly for now, thanks!